# By mistake I changed the ownership of /var directory.

Tags: debian, permissions, var

Instead of changing the ownership of /var/www directory, I changed the ownership of /var directory recursively (couple of days back). Now owner of every directory in /var is www-data. All my sites are down and showing "Error establishing a database connection."

There are 12 directories in /var folder :
backups,  cache,  lib,  local,  lock,  log,  mail,  opt,  run,  spool,  tmp,  www

Now how I will rectify my mistake? I don't know which directory is owned by which user. Do I have to find about the owner of each folder one by one and change its permission settings or there is some other way to do it ?

(Operating system : Debian 7.8)

Comment: Restore from, or consult the backups you ought to have to determine the proper owners.

Comment: It is a waste of time doing anything but restoring.

Answer (score 1):

Install fresh Debian on separate server. Check owners and set the same on your current server.

Comment: This doesn't help with the files installed manually by the user.